# Can I prevent a batch file to be executed by more than 1 user at the same time

Tags: windows, batch-file, user-management

I have a batch file which can update a web project and clean/rebuild it. I made it executable for network users. Now I want to make the batch executable only by one user at the same time. Like synchronize object in programming languages.

Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: Are you talking about an executable (as per your subject) or a batch file (as per your question text)?

Comment: You want to prevent two executions at the same time? Or do you want to allow multiple people to run it, but only allow a given user the ability to run it once? And as Harry Johnston asked - is this a batch file or an exe file?

Comment: thanks for ask, it is a batch file, and exactly i want to limit only one user can run it in once time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution to check if batch file is already running is using file system.

The batch file can check if a file exists and denies execution in this case, otherwise it creates the file, runs the commands and finally deletes the file.

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Temp\BatchLock.txt" goto BatchRunning
echo Batch file is running by %username%.>C:\Temp\BatchLock.txt

rem All other commands of the batch file

del C:\Temp\BatchLock.txt
goto :EOF

:BatchRunning
type C:\Temp\BatchLock.txt
echo/
echo Please run the batch later again.
echo/
echo Press any key to exit ...
pause >nul
```

Of course `C:\Temp` is not a good storage location for the lock text file. It must be a directory which is identical for all users, a directory on server with write permissions for all users.